# How would I get my horizontal navigation bar to span the full width?

Tags: css, html

I am making a website and I want the Navbar to span the full page. how would I do this? I think the way would be somewhere withing the `ul.navbar a` Element.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Simple Site</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
<div id="body">
<center>
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="biography.html">Biography</a></li>
    </ul>
    </center>
</div>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";


#container {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:960px;
    background-color:#666666;
}

#body {
    background-color:#666666;
    width:960px;
    height:500px;
    border:2px solid #FFFFFF;
    margin-top:50px auto;
}

.navbar {
    position:relative;
    list-style:none;
    border-bottom:none;
    float:left;
}

ul.navbar li {
    float:left;
}

ul.navbar a {
    background-color:#66FF33;

    margin:0px;
    padding:5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#
}

ul.navbar a:hover {
    width:8em;
    margin:0px;
    background-color:#33FFD7;
    padding:5px;
}

body {
    background-color:#333333;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, but are you asking for **how to display an html element to full width** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/4s6wn/

Here, I made a fiddle with what you wanted.  Instead of using `float:left` on the `li`s, you can use `display:inline-block` and then `text-align:center` on the `.navbar`

I also put the green background color on .navbar instead.

---

If you want to make the kinks equal over the span of the page  add `width: 19%` to `ul.navbar li`. This will have to be adjusted if you add extra links though.

See http://jsfiddle.net/u4se9/ for the `a` tags to have `display:block;width:100%;` in case you find the `ul.navbar a:hover` too small.

In http://jsfiddle.net/pdvhD/ I centered fixed the padding on the left.